# Battery voltage dropping without load: what does this say about its health?

Tags: batteries

I have three AGM batteries (VARTA LA95, 12V, 95Ah) that I want to connect in parallel in a battery bank.

They were connected to a Victron charger for a long time and now that I turned it off, I began reading the voltage daily *just for fun*. They were all connected to the same charger output.

One of them is clearly behaving differently, but I can't figure out what that means.

My question is:

- Is battery #3 "healthy"?
- Bonus question: What happens if I use it in parallel with the other two?

| timestamp | batt #1 | batt #2 | batt #3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t0 + 24h | 12.90 V | 12.83 V | 12.51 V |
| t0 + 48h | 12.90 V | 12.83 V | 12.48 V |
| t0 + 72h | 12.90 V | 12.83 V | 12.45 V |
| t0 + 96h | 12.89 V | 12.83 V | 12.43 V |
| t0 + 120h | 12.89 V | 12.83 V | 12.40 V |

(t0 is when I removed the charger)

Comment: To answer your bonus question: Don't connect batteries in parallel unless they've been charged in parallel (or by a charger designed for that use case).

Comment: These ones were charged in parallel and they all are the same model, so I expect it to be fine. I was only surprised to find that one of them looses charge much faster than the other two. But they were all bought used and from different sellers...

Answer (score 2):

AGM batteries have a self discharge rate of [1%-3%/month](https://www.solar-electric.com/learning-center/deep-cycle-battery-faq.html/#:%7E:text=AGM%27s%20have%20a%20very%20low,days%20of%20being%20totally%20discharged.)  Assuming for the moment that self-discharge will be linear with time (probably as a worst case), extrapolating your 120 hours to 30 days, shows battery 3 to fall within the 1%-3% range.

Comment: That's a good way to look at it; I forgot to estimate the self-discharge. But I get a rate of over 5% for battery #3 and less than 1% for the other two. It's probably better to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Bonus question: What happens if I use it in parallel with the other two?

Nothing spectacular will happen, *maybe* tiny sparks when connected together, and then they will even out. The batteries will work as one unit.

Comment: This got me thinking and I suppose what will happen is that #3 will slowly drain from #1 and #2 and the whole SoC and voltage will be a sort-of-average of my values in the table. And the sparks will be due to the current flowing into #3.